# How to enable noise suppression and audio mirroring in WebRTC

Tags: audio, webrtc

How can I enable noise suppression and audio mirroring in WebRTC?

What I tried is to put in the media constraints

```
audio: {
    mandatory: {
        googNoiseSupression: true
        googAudioMirroring: true
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. After the browser asks permission to share the mic and I click on "Allow", then nothing happens.

I got the options from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/mediaconstraintsinterface.cc. Is there somewhere else a list of the media constraints that can be used?

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you use `getUserMedia` you have to then *do something* with the resulting stream. Are you attaching it to the dom? Streaming it over a peer connection?

Comment: I'm using getUserMedia and both attaching it to a video element and stream it to a peer connection. What I'm trying to achieve is to have better sound quality.

Comment: So is any of that working? Are you still getting an audio stream, or getting an error? You say "nothing happens" but does that mean "adding the constraint has no affect on the stream" or "adding the constraint causes the user media request to fail"?

Comment: Finally it worked with `googNoiseSupression`, but not with `googAudioMirroring`. With the latter, calling getUserMedia does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work, but only with googNoiseSupression. Also adding googAudioMirroring and calling getUserMedia does nothing.